# SQL lottery query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count, sql-order-by

I have a simple table of 7 columns

```
Week ¦ 1st ¦ 2nd ¦ 3rd ¦ 4th ¦ 5th ¦ 6th ¦
```

Each week, my father adds Saturdays UK lottery numbers to a simple PHP script that I created. He has early onset Alzheimers and tries to keep his brain active.  Tonight he asked me a question about the database.  He asked me if it was possible to see the 6 most popular numbers.

I tried to create a simple SQL query:

```
SELECT 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, 6th, COUNT(*) AS 'foo' FROM `dad` GROUP BY 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, 6th ORDER BY foo DESC
```

But the results weren't as I expected.

```
1st 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 6th foo
2   6   8   32  33  35  1
3   6   12  17  35  40  1
3   6   31  43  46  53  1
etc
```

What I hoped would happen would be for the table to merge into one column, and then count and have a simple result, something like:

```
Number   Count
2        1
3        2
6        3
8        1
```

And then maybe put it in ascending order.  I can then use that SQL query to create a simple table for him to show the most common numbers.

I'm thinking of doing a general SQL query

```
SELECT 1st FROM `dad`
```

Then creating an Array with the results, then adding

```
SELECT 2nd FROM `dad`
```

To the end of the Array and continuing for all 6 columns, then using PHP to count the numbers individually.

Is there a quicker way?

Comment: In MySQL 8.x you can use `RANK()`. What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @TheImpaler Will that unpivot them?

Comment: @TheImpaler I am using PHPMyAdmin to test the SQL

Comment: Seriously consider revising your schema. A database table is not a spreadsheet. It's disappointed that no one's mentioned this already - oh, well almost no one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
select
  n, cnt
from (
  select
    n,
    count(*) as cnt
  from (
    select `1st` as n from `dad` union all
    select `2nd` from `dad` union all
    select `3rd` from `dad` union all  
    select `4th` from `dad` union all
    select `5th` from `dad` union all
    select `6th` from `dad`
  ) x
  group by n
) y
order by cnt desc
limit 6
```

Comment: This code works almost perfectly, when I run it, I get a result like this:
21, 42, 44, 3, 6, 28
I added
ORDER BY cnt DESC, n ASC
and got the result
21, 3, 6, 28, 35, 42
so it shows number order after count.

Is there a way to change it to get the highest 6 count, then order from lowest number to highest?

Comment: @TonySavage Yes, you can enclose the current query in another external one and order on this external one. For example: `select * from ( <current-query> ) z order by n ASC`.

Answer (score 3):

Your first effort should go into fixing your data model. Each number should be stored on a separate row rather than in a column, like:

```
week    pos    num
   1      1      6
   1      2      8
   1      3     32
```

Then your query would be a simple aggregate query:

```
select num, count(*) no_picks from dad group by num order by no_picks desc
```

For your given table structure, you would need to unpivot the columns to rows. In MySQL, you can use `union all` for this:

```
select num, count(*) no_picks
from (
    select `1st` num from dad
    union all select `2nd` from dad
    union all select `3rd` from dad
    union all select `4th` from dad
    union all select `5th` from dad
    union all select `6th` from dad
) t
group by num 
order by no_picks
```